# Capacity Scheduler queue issue

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to setup capacity scheduler queues in my standalone node and I am having an issue with that.

I was able to create the queues which I am able to see them in Cloudera Manager via the UI but when I login and try to do mapred queue -list, it does not show the queues I have setup. It only shows the default queue which i have omitted from the config.

**Capacity Scheduler Config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

<property>
<name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.queues</name>
<value>card,bank,digital</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.capacity</name>
<value>100</value>
</property>


<property>
<name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.digital.capacity</name>
<value>41</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.card.capacity</name>
<value>29</value>
</property>


<property>
<name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.bank.capacity</name>
<value>30</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.digital.acl_submit_applications</name>
<value>cloudera</value>
 </property>
```

**Below logs**

```
    2014-02-18 08:09:54,940 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.LeafQueue: Initializing card
capacity = 0.29 [= (float) configuredCapacity / 100 ]
asboluteCapacity = 0.29 [= parentAbsoluteCapacity * capacity ]
maxCapacity = 1.0 [= configuredMaxCapacity ]
absoluteMaxCapacity = 1.0 [= 1.0 maximumCapacity undefined, (parentAbsoluteMaxCapacity * maximumCapacity) / 100 otherwise ]
userLimit = 100 [= configuredUserLimit ]
userLimitFactor = 1.0 [= configuredUserLimitFactor ]
maxApplications = 2900 [= configuredMaximumSystemApplicationsPerQueue or (int)(configuredMaximumSystemApplications * absoluteCapacity)]
maxApplicationsPerUser = 2900 [= (int)(maxApplications * (userLimit / 100.0f) * userLimitFactor) ]
maxActiveApplications = 1 [= max((int)ceil((clusterResourceMemory / minimumAllocation) * maxAMResourcePerQueuePercent * absoluteMaxCapacity),1) ]
maxActiveAppsUsingAbsCap = 1 [= max((int)ceil((clusterResourceMemory / minimumAllocation) *maxAMResourcePercent * absoluteCapacity),1) ]
maxActiveApplicationsPerUser = 1 [= max((int)(maxActiveApplications * (userLimit / 100.0f) * userLimitFactor),1) ]
usedCapacity = 0.0 [= usedResourcesMemory / (clusterResourceMemory * absoluteCapacity)]
absoluteUsedCapacity = 0.0 [= usedResourcesMemory / clusterResourceMemory]
maxAMResourcePerQueuePercent = 0.1 [= configuredMaximumAMResourcePercent ]
minimumAllocationFactor = 0.875 [= (float)(maximumAllocationMemory - minimumAllocationMemory) / maximumAllocationMemory ]
numContainers = 0 [= currentNumContainers ]
state = RUNNING [= configuredState ]
acls = ADMINISTER_QUEUE: SUBMIT_APPLICATIONS:  [= configuredAcls ]

2014-02-18 08:09:54,941 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: Initialized queue: card: capacity=0.29, absoluteCapacity=0.29, usedResources=<memory:0, vCores:0>usedCapacity=0.0, absoluteUsedCapacity=0.0, numApps=0, numContainers=0
2014-02-18 08:09:54,941 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.LeafQueue: Initializing bank
capacity = 0.3 [= (float) configuredCapacity / 100 ]
asboluteCapacity = 0.3 [= parentAbsoluteCapacity * capacity ]
maxCapacity = 1.0 [= configuredMaxCapacity ]
absoluteMaxCapacity = 1.0 [= 1.0 maximumCapacity undefined, (parentAbsoluteMaxCapacity * maximumCapacity) / 100 otherwise ]
userLimit = 100 [= configuredUserLimit ]
userLimitFactor = 1.0 [= configuredUserLimitFactor ]
maxApplications = 3000 [= configuredMaximumSystemApplicationsPerQueue or (int)(configuredMaximumSystemApplications * absoluteCapacity)]
maxApplicationsPerUser = 3000 [= (int)(maxApplications * (userLimit / 100.0f) * userLimitFactor) ]
maxActiveApplications = 1 [= max((int)ceil((clusterResourceMemory / minimumAllocation) * maxAMResourcePerQueuePercent * absoluteMaxCapacity),1) ]
maxActiveAppsUsingAbsCap = 1 [= max((int)ceil((clusterResourceMemory / minimumAllocation) *maxAMResourcePercent * absoluteCapacity),1) ]
maxActiveApplicationsPerUser = 1 [= max((int)(maxActiveApplications * (userLimit / 100.0f) * userLimitFactor),1) ]
usedCapacity = 0.0 [= usedResourcesMemory / (clusterResourceMemory * absoluteCapacity)]
absoluteUsedCapacity = 0.0 [= usedResourcesMemory / clusterResourceMemory]
maxAMResourcePerQueuePercent = 0.1 [= configuredMaximumAMResourcePercent ]
minimumAllocationFactor = 0.875 [= (float)(maximumAllocationMemory - minimumAllocationMemory) / maximumAllocationMemory ]
numContainers = 0 [= currentNumContainers ]
state = RUNNING [= configuredState ]
acls = ADMINISTER_QUEUE: SUBMIT_APPLICATIONS:  [= configuredAcls ]

2014-02-18 08:09:54,941 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: Initialized queue: bank: capacity=0.3, absoluteCapacity=0.3, usedResources=<memory:0, vCores:0>usedCapacity=0.0, absoluteUsedCapacity=0.0, numApps=0, numContainers=0
2014-02-18 08:09:54,942 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.LeafQueue: Initializing digital
capacity = 0.41 [= (float) configuredCapacity / 100 ]
asboluteCapacity = 0.41 [= parentAbsoluteCapacity * capacity ]
maxCapacity = 1.0 [= configuredMaxCapacity ]
absoluteMaxCapacity = 1.0 [= 1.0 maximumCapacity undefined, (parentAbsoluteMaxCapacity * maximumCapacity) / 100 otherwise ]
userLimit = 100 [= configuredUserLimit ]
userLimitFactor = 1.0 [= configuredUserLimitFactor ]
maxApplications = 4100 [= configuredMaximumSystemApplicationsPerQueue or (int)(configuredMaximumSystemApplications * absoluteCapacity)]
maxApplicationsPerUser = 4100 [= (int)(maxApplications * (userLimit / 100.0f) * userLimitFactor) ]
maxActiveApplications = 1 [= max((int)ceil((clusterResourceMemory / minimumAllocation) * maxAMResourcePerQueuePercent * absoluteMaxCapacity),1) ]
maxActiveAppsUsingAbsCap = 1 [= max((int)ceil((clusterResourceMemory / minimumAllocation) *maxAMResourcePercent * absoluteCapacity),1) ]
maxActiveApplicationsPerUser = 1 [= max((int)(maxActiveApplications * (userLimit / 100.0f) * userLimitFactor),1) ]
usedCapacity = 0.0 [= usedResourcesMemory / (clusterResourceMemory * absoluteCapacity)]
absoluteUsedCapacity = 0.0 [= usedResourcesMemory / clusterResourceMemory]
maxAMResourcePerQueuePercent = 0.1 [= configuredMaximumAMResourcePercent ]
minimumAllocationFactor = 0.875 [= (float)(maximumAllocationMemory - minimumAllocationMemory) / maximumAllocationMemory ]
numContainers = 0 [= currentNumContainers ]
state = RUNNING [= configuredState ]
acls = ADMINISTER_QUEUE: SUBMIT_APPLICATIONS:cloudera  [= configuredAcls ]

2014-02-18 08:09:54,942 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: Initialized queue: digital: capacity=0.41, absoluteCapacity=0.41, usedResources=<memory:0, vCores:0>usedCapacity=0.0, absoluteUsedCapacity=0.0, numApps=0, numContainers=0
2014-02-18 08:09:54,942 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: Initialized queue: root: numChildQueue= 3, capacity=1.0, absoluteCapacity=1.0, usedResources=<memory:0, vCores:0>usedCapacity=0.0, numApps=0, numContainers=0
2014-02-18 08:09:54,942 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.ParentQueue: root, capacity=1.0, asboluteCapacity=1.0, maxCapacity=1.0, asboluteMaxCapacity=1.0, state=RUNNING, acls=ADMINISTER_QUEUE:*SUBMIT_APPLICATIONS:*
2014-02-18 08:09:54,942 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.LeafQueue: Initializing card
capacity = 0.29 [= (float) configuredCapacity / 100 ]
asboluteCapacity = 0.29 [= parentAbsoluteCapacity * capacity ]
maxCapacity = 1.0 [= configuredMaxCapacity ]
absoluteMaxCapacity = 1.0 [= 1.0 maximumCapacity undefined, (parentAbsoluteMaxCapacity * maximumCapacity) / 100 otherwise ]
userLimit = 100 [= configuredUserLimit ]
userLimitFactor = 1.0 [= configuredUserLimitFactor ]
maxApplications = 2900 [= configuredMaximumSystemApplicationsPerQueue or (int)(configuredMaximumSystemApplications * absoluteCapacity)]
maxApplicationsPerUser = 2900 [= (int)(maxApplications * (userLimit / 100.0f) * userLimitFactor) ]
maxActiveApplications = 1 [= max((int)ceil((clusterResourceMemory / minimumAllocation) * maxAMResourcePerQueuePercent * absoluteMaxCapacity),1) ]
maxActiveAppsUsingAbsCap = 1 [= max((int)ceil((clusterResourceMemory / minimumAllocation) *maxAMResourcePercent * absoluteCapacity),1) ]
maxActiveApplicationsPerUser = 1 [= max((int)(maxActiveApplications * (userLimit / 100.0f) * userLimitFactor),1) ]
usedCapacity = 0.0 [= usedResourcesMemory / (clusterResourceMemory * absoluteCapacity)]
absoluteUsedCapacity = 0.0 [= usedResourcesMemory / clusterResourceMemory]
maxAMResourcePerQueuePercent = 0.1 [= configuredMaximumAMResourcePercent ]
minimumAllocationFactor = 0.875 [= (float)(maximumAllocationMemory - minimumAllocationMemory) / maximumAllocationMemory ]
numContainers = 0 [= currentNumContainers ]
state = RUNNING [= configuredState ]
acls = ADMINISTER_QUEUE: SUBMIT_APPLICATIONS:  [= configuredAcls ]

2014-02-18 08:09:54,942 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.ParentQueue: root: re-configured queue: card: capacity=0.29, absoluteCapacity=0.29, usedResources=<memory:0, vCores:0>usedCapacity=0.0, absoluteUsedCapacity=0.0, numApps=0, numContainers=0
2014-02-18 08:09:54,942 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.LeafQueue: Initializing bank
capacity = 0.3 [= (float) configuredCapacity / 100 ]
asboluteCapacity = 0.3 [= parentAbsoluteCapacity * capacity ]
maxCapacity = 1.0 [= configuredMaxCapacity ]
absoluteMaxCapacity = 1.0 [= 1.0 maximumCapacity undefined, (parentAbsoluteMaxCapacity * maximumCapacity) / 100 otherwise ]
userLimit = 100 [= configuredUserLimit ]
userLimitFactor = 1.0 [= configuredUserLimitFactor ]
maxApplications = 3000 [= configuredMaximumSystemApplicationsPerQueue or (int)(configuredMaximumSystemApplications * absoluteCapacity)]
maxApplicationsPerUser = 3000 [= (int)(maxApplications * (userLimit / 100.0f) * userLimitFactor) ]
maxActiveApplications = 1 [= max((int)ceil((clusterResourceMemory / minimumAllocation) * maxAMResourcePerQueuePercent * absoluteMaxCapacity),1) ]
maxActiveAppsUsingAbsCap = 1 [= max((int)ceil((clusterResourceMemory / minimumAllocation) *maxAMResourcePercent * absoluteCapacity),1) ]
maxActiveApplicationsPerUser = 1 [= max((int)(maxActiveApplications * (userLimit / 100.0f) * userLimitFactor),1) ]
usedCapacity = 0.0 [= usedResourcesMemory / (clusterResourceMemory * absoluteCapacity)]
absoluteUsedCapacity = 0.0 [= usedResourcesMemory / clusterResourceMemory]
maxAMResourcePerQueuePercent = 0.1 [= configuredMaximumAMResourcePercent ]
minimumAllocationFactor = 0.875 [= (float)(maximumAllocationMemory - minimumAllocationMemory) / maximumAllocationMemory ]
numContainers = 0 [= currentNumContainers ]
state = RUNNING [= configuredState ]
acls = ADMINISTER_QUEUE: SUBMIT_APPLICATIONS:  [= configuredAcls ]

2014-02-18 08:09:54,943 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.ParentQueue: root: re-configured queue: bank: capacity=0.3, absoluteCapacity=0.3, usedResources=<memory:0, vCores:0>usedCapacity=0.0, absoluteUsedCapacity=0.0, numApps=0, numContainers=0
2014-02-18 08:09:54,943 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.LeafQueue: Initializing digital
capacity = 0.41 [= (float) configuredCapacity / 100 ]
asboluteCapacity = 0.41 [= parentAbsoluteCapacity * capacity ]
maxCapacity = 1.0 [= configuredMaxCapacity ]
absoluteMaxCapacity = 1.0 [= 1.0 maximumCapacity undefined, (parentAbsoluteMaxCapacity * maximumCapacity) / 100 otherwise ]
userLimit = 100 [= configuredUserLimit ]
userLimitFactor = 1.0 [= configuredUserLimitFactor ]
maxApplications = 4100 [= configuredMaximumSystemApplicationsPerQueue or (int)(configuredMaximumSystemApplications * absoluteCapacity)]
maxApplicationsPerUser = 4100 [= (int)(maxApplications * (userLimit / 100.0f) * userLimitFactor) ]
maxActiveApplications = 1 [= max((int)ceil((clusterResourceMemory / minimumAllocation) * maxAMResourcePerQueuePercent * absoluteMaxCapacity),1) ]
maxActiveAppsUsingAbsCap = 1 [= max((int)ceil((clusterResourceMemory / minimumAllocation) *maxAMResourcePercent * absoluteCapacity),1) ]
maxActiveApplicationsPerUser = 1 [= max((int)(maxActiveApplications * (userLimit / 100.0f) * userLimitFactor),1) ]
usedCapacity = 0.0 [= usedResourcesMemory / (clusterResourceMemory * absoluteCapacity)]
absoluteUsedCapacity = 0.0 [= usedResourcesMemory / clusterResourceMemory]
maxAMResourcePerQueuePercent = 0.1 [= configuredMaximumAMResourcePercent ]
minimumAllocationFactor = 0.875 [= (float)(maximumAllocationMemory - minimumAllocationMemory) / maximumAllocationMemory ]
numContainers = 0 [= currentNumContainers ]
state = RUNNING [= configuredState ]
acls = ADMINISTER_QUEUE: SUBMIT_APPLICATIONS:cloudera  [= configuredAcls ]

2014-02-18 08:09:54,943 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.ParentQueue: root: re-configured queue: digital: capacity=0.41, absoluteCapacity=0.41, usedResources=<memory:0, vCores:0>usedCapacity=0.0, absoluteUsedCapacity=0.0, numApps=0, numContainers=0
2014-02-18 08:09:54,943 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAuditLogger: USER=cloudera IP=127.0.0.1    OPERATION=refreshQueues TARGET=AdminService RESULT=SUCCESS
2014-02-18 08:10:19,772 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.AdminService: RM Admin: refreshAdminAcls invoked by user cloudera
2014-02-18 08:10:19,792 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAuditLogger: USER=cloudera IP=127.0.0.1    OPERATION=refreshAdminAcls  TARGET=AdminService RESULT=SUCCESS
```

**Mapred command output**

```
    Queue Name : default
Queue State : running
Scheduling Info : Queue configuration
Capacity Percentage: 100.0%
User Limit: 100%
Priority Supported: NO
-------------
Map tasks
Capacity: 2 slots
Used capacity: 0 (0.0% of Capacity)
Running tasks: 0
-------------
Reduce tasks
Capacity: 2 slots
Used capacity: 0 (0.0% of Capacity)
Running tasks: 0
-------------
Job info
Number of Waiting Jobs: 0
Number of Initializing Jobs: 0
Number of users who have submitted jobs: 0
```

Comment: Did you also set yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class parameter to org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler in conf/yarn-site.xml ? You may also need to restart cluster for change to take effect, if you modified queue list after restart we need to run "$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/bin/yarn rmadmin -refreshQueues" to refresh queue list.

Comment: Thanks rvr for the reply. I tried these already and still it does not work.

Comment: Figured out the issue. Root cause was the client configuration was deployed but somehow /etc/hadoop/conf was not pointed to the latest configuration deployed. I changed that manually and it worked

Answer (score 0):

change the below properties in capacity-scheduler.xml to use 100% resource in user queue

`yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.it.user-limit-factor=2
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.price.user-limit-factor=1`